# command to remove agents once they have been taken from a given storage anylogic

Tags: anylogic

i have this code:

```
int nRetrieved = nForRetrieve.getIntValue();
int storageSize = 0; 
int b=orangeStorageSize; 
int a=0;
Storage retStorage =  null;
if (b == a) {
switch (retrieveRadio.getValue()) {
    case 0:         
        retStorage = greenStorage;
        break;  
    case 1:
        retStorage = blueStorage;
        break;
    case 2:
        retStorage = redStorage;
        break;
}
}
else  {
       retStorage= orangeStorage;
       while (retStorage.size()>0) {
       remove_retStorage;
       }
}
storageSize = retStorage.size();
if (nRetrieved > storageSize)
nRetrieved = storageSize;
for (int i = storageSize; i > storageSize - nRetrieved; i--)
    enter.take((SKU)retStorage.getAgents().get(i-1));
```

practically what I'm working with is a warehouse where the retStorage function represents the quantity of pallets to be picked up and taken to the machines, my cnc machines will subsequently generate new pallets that will be placed in the orange warehouse, now when I go to make the second pick if there are pallets in my orange warehouse, I'll go and pick them up, otherwise I'll pick them up from the other warehouses.
I would like to insert a comment that if I go to pick up from the orange warehouse once processed by the cnc machine these pallets are eliminated how can I do?

I tried to use the remove() but it tells me that it is not compatible with the type storage

Comment: Can you perhaps simplify the question? In general I suggest you read the documentation for the traceln() function and get comfortable using it. Here you can make logical prints to the console, and you can work carefully with your model logic. Definitely make it a habit :)